# Why won't my AJAX post redirect to the correct ActionResult

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So pretty simple set-up and I know I'm missing something stupid here.

JS:

```
$("#Affiliate").change(function () {
                var selectedItem = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@(Url.Action("ChangeOrg", "ScheduleStatistic"))",
                    data: { "organazation": selectedItem }
                });
            });
```

View:

```
<select id="Affiliate" class="form_select" style="z-index: 3000; width: 100%;">
                                    <option value="Org1">Foo</option>
                                    <option value="Org2">Bar</option>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ChangeOrg(string organazation)
    {
        switch (organazation)
        {
            case "Org1":
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { orgURL = "URL_Org1" });
                break;
            case "Org2":
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { orgURL = "URL_Org2" });
                break;

            default:
                return this.View();
        }

    }
```

However, while it gets to that action result... it never does the redirectToAction however if i type in the URL "Localhost/ChangeOrg?Organazation=Org1" It goes there correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you put in a breakpoint in your Controller, what is the value of `organization`?

Comment: I get the correct return value it is "Org1" or "Org2" depending on the DDL selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server-side redirect is actually done through client-side trip. Redirects are not relevant to ajax requests, so the browser never calls the redirected url.

What is the supposed outcome of `Index` action and how are you going to use it on `succes` of ajax?

Depending on what you really need, this may work for you:

```
public ActionResult ChangeOrg(string organazation)
{
    switch (organazation)
    {
        case "Org1":
            return Index("URL_Org1");
            break;
        case "Org2":
            return Index("URL_Org2");
            break;

        default:
            return this.View();
    }

}
```

**Update:**

If the user should be redirected to a different page when `Affiliate` value changes, then you do not need `ajax`:

```
$("#Affiliate").change(function () {
  var selectedItem = $(this).val();
  var url = "@(Url.Action("ChangeOrg", "ScheduleStatistic"))?organazation=" + selectedItem,
  window.location.assign(url);
});
```

Comment: So, What I need to do is ultimately, depending on a selected item in a dropdownlist redirect the user to the action ChangeOrg with the argument of the selectedItem Value.

For example: If I select "Foo" in the drop down I want the user redirected to Localhost/ChangeOrg?Organization=Org1

Comment: Worked great! If I had the rep, I'd upvote you but I did mark correct. Thanks so much Igor!

Answer (score 0):

ajax won't redirect.  To redirect you need to put it in success on the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "@(Url.Action("ChangeOrg", "ScheduleStatistic"))",
    data: { "organazation": selectedItem }
    success: function(result){
        if(result.Success){
            window.location = "@Url.Action(newaction, newcontroller)"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Returning the redirect url in the result object would also work, especially if it should be dynamically determined as in the example code.